# Queries to delete a listview item

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

I'm trying to create a code where if you long press an item from a list view, it will create a choice to delete it.

This code is for an account book app where the sum of the expenses would be displayed in the top layer of the app, and the numbers will add up to the sum of the expenses. As shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjSgt.jpg

myDBHelper activity's code:

```
class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public MyDBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, "My_Account_Data.db", null, 4);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ("
                + "%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "%s TEXT, "
                + "%s INTEGER, "
                + "%s TEXT);", TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID, KEY_CONTEXT, KEY_PRICE, KEY_DATE);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query = String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s", TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

main activity's code part where the action takes place:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete)
                            .setTitle("Deletion")
                            .setMessage("Do you really want to delete this content?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    EditText eContext = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.edit_context );
                                    EditText ePrice = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.edit_price );
                                    String contexts = eContext.getText().toString();
                                    int price = Integer.parseInt( ePrice.getText().toString() );
                                    String today_Date = getToday_date();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Value Written" + contexts +", " + price + ", " + today_Date);

                                    String query = String.format(
                                            "DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + contexts + price, View_DATE);
                                    db.execSQL( query ); // What to write in here?

                                    String queryPriceSum = String.format( " SELECT SUM(price) FROM %s WHERE date = '%s'", TABLE_NAME, View_DATE);
                                    cursor = db.rawQuery( queryPriceSum, null );
                                    cursor.moveToNext();
                                    String sum = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0));
                                    Log.d(TAG, "sum : " + sum);
                                    sum_view.setText(sum);

                                    // cursor.requery();
                                    String querySelectAll = String.format( "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE date = '%s'", TABLE_NAME, View_DATE);
                                    cursor = db.rawQuery( querySelectAll, null );
                                    myAdapter.changeCursor( cursor );
                                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    eContext.setText( "" );
                                    ePrice.setText( "" );
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

cursor adapter activity:

```
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
        View v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.list_item, parent,false );
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView item_context = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.item_context );
        TextView item_price = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.item_price );

        String contexts = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( MainActivity.KEY_CONTEXT ) );
        String price = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( MainActivity.KEY_PRICE ) );

        Log.d(TAG, contexts + ", " + price);

        item_context.setText( contexts );
        item_price.setText( price );

    }
```

Deletion of the contents will result in subtraction on the expenses' sum part, and removal of the selected content.

After making changes according to MikeT's answer I got this error:

> 2019-06-21 08:32:57.052 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
>       2019-06-21 08:32:57.188 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/ViewRootImpl@ef6be96[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
>       2019-06-21 08:32:57.190 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/AbsListView: onTouchUp() mTouchMode : -1
>       2019-06-21 08:32:57.650 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/ViewRootImpl@1632a00[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
>       2019-06-21 08:32:57.751 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/ViewRootImpl@1632a00[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
>       2019-06-21 08:32:57.768 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>       2019-06-21 08:32:57.770 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: org.androidtown.mycalendar, PID: 17280
>           java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
>               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
>               at org.androidtown.mycalendar.MainActivity$2$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:128)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
>       2019-06-21 08:32:57.790 17280-17280/org.androidtown.mycalendar I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17280 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

> db.execSQL( query ); // What to write in here?

That is fine what is not fine is :-

```
String query = String.format("DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + contexts + price, View_DATE);
```

That is the WHERE clause is unlikely to be of any benefit as there doesn't appear to be any comparison. Instead it appears that you are generating something along the lines of

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE some_valuesome_pricesome_date
```

That's not going to work, likely because the WHERE clause will not be a valid column name and even if it were it would then result in unpredictable deletions as it would check the column's data to see if it were 0 or not 0 (if the data starts with a non-numeric then 0, if starts with a numeric then very likely 1). Any rows that result in 1 would get deleted. As per [SQL As Understood By SQLite - expression- Boolean Expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Rather you'd want something like

```
String query = String.format("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + KEY_CONTEXT + "= '" + contexts + "' AND " + KEY_PRICE + "=" + ePrice.getText().toString() + " AND " + KEY_DATE + "='%s'",VIEW_DATE);
```

Or better from an SQL injection prevention perspective :-

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + KEY_CONTEXT + "=? AND " + KEY_PRICE + "=? AND " + KEY_DATE + "=?";
db.execSQL(query,new String[]{contexts,ePrice.getText().toString(),String.format("%s",VIEW_DATE)});
```

Or less prone to syntax errors as the **[delete](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D))** convenience method builds much of the SQL :-

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME,KEY_CONTEXT+"=? AND "+KEY_PRICE+"=? AND "+KEY_DATE+"=?",new String[]{contexts,ePrice.getText().toString(),String.format("%s",VIEW_DATE)});
```

- Note that the above line replaces two lines, the line that sets the value of **query** and the lines that executes the SQL.

## Notes

- There is no need to get the value from the EditText ePrice, risk the exception of parsing it to an integer to then just convert it to a string for the resultant query.
- The above code is in-principle code, it has not been checked or run and may therefore have some errors.
- The typical way would be to utilise the rows's column that aliases the rowid (i.e. the column you have defined with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`) as this value will uniquely identify the respective row.

Comment: The program only crashed after I edited the part like so. Is there anything that I've been doing wrong?

Comment: Without details of *"The program crashed"* it would only be conjecture. You need to include the stack-trace which identifies what caused the crash and where the crash occurred. One thing that will cause a crash, is if an empty cursor is returned due to the selection criteria. That is you should always check the result of any **move?????** method (e.g **moveToNext**, **moveToFirst** etc), if it's false then you will not be positioned at a row and thus any attempt to get data from the cursor will fail with an index bounds error.

Comment: I see, thank you for the correction. As I don't use Stack Overflow much, your correction is highly appreciated. I included a crash log here in this link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CNI9z2mOublNnK5MZIGKTgOdv0Pq7CU4

Comment: Ok add the number "" to "" what number is that? i.e. you cannot convert "" to a number that is your issue. (see the first NOTE in the answer) Try commenting out the line `int price = Integer.parseInt( ePrice.getText().toString() );` as per the note it's useless BUT why is it empty? Are you not validating what can be typed as a number (hint in the layout use input_type so that only numbers can be entered).